# Reduction of irregular graphs, to regular graphs, while preserving hamiltonicity

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, reductions, open-problem, hamiltonian-paths

I am wondering if this is a topic that has had research done...

If I could reduce irregular graphs to regular graphs (including replacing redundant node clusters with dummy nodes), while ensuring that hamiltonicity wouldn't be lost - that would be very useful for me.

Anyone know anything about this?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, there is a reduction to 3-regular graphs.  See this paper [http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/810000/803884/p47-garey.pdf] on the page numbered 54.

Comment: link isn't working for me.  what is the name of the paper?

Comment: Oops -- it's "The Planar Hamiltonian Circuit Problem is NP-Complete" by Garey, Johnson, Tarjan (see also references within which might have more direct/alternate proofs).